# Cannot generate NSUUID in class initializer - Apple Mach-O Linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid, nsuuid

I'm writing an iOS game using Sprite Kit (so targeting iOS 7+) and I'm running into an issue when initializing a `gameObject` (custom class).

If I try and set a UUID for the game's ID, the build fails (see below for the error message); removing the call to the `getUUID` method fixes the problem, so I'm pretty sure that's where the problem lies.

The `getUUID` method is inside a helper class, which is imported in the Prefix.pch (and so should be available to all other file?).

Here's the `helpers.h`:

```
NSString *getUUID();

@interface helpers : NSObject

@end
```

And `helpers.m`:

```
@implementation helpers

+(NSString *)getUUID
{
    NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
    NSString *uuidString = [uuid UUIDString];

    return uuidString;
}

@end
```

Finally, here's what the `gameObject.m` looks like:

```
static NSString *gameID = nil;
static NSDate *gameStarted = nil;
static NSNumber *venue = nil;
static NSNumber *timerDuration = nil;
static NSArray *players = nil;
static NSArray *playerMoves = nil;
static NSNumber *winner = nil;

@implementation gameObject

+(void) initialize
{
    if(! gameID)
    {
        // generate a new guid for this game
        gameID = getUUID();
    }
}

@end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_getUUID", referenced from:
      +[gameObject initialize] in gameObject.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've checked all the common fixes mentioned for this error on SO: my build settings architecture is set as `arm64 arm7 arm7s`, the files have their targets set correctly, and all my `.m` files are included in the build.

Any ideas where I've gone wrong? I'm still very new to Objective-C, so all of this is kind of flailing in the dark for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helpers.h file declares a **function**:

```
NSString *getUUID();
```

and the helpers.m file defines a class **method**:

```
+(NSString *)getUUID;
```

which is not the same. So you have to decide which one you want. For example, change the
.h file to

```
@interface helpers : NSObject
+(NSString *)getUUID;
@end
```

and then call it like

```
gameID = [helpers getUUID];
```

(Side note: Class names usually start with a capital letter: "Helpers".)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Like I say, I'm still learning Objective-C/C++ so I'm making lots of stupid errors like this at the moment. I'm learning from my mistakes - slowly - thanks to helpful people like you, so Upvote and Accept on the way.